# how to handle the DataMemo of RaveReports to display correctly

Tags: delphi, report, rave-reports

i created a Reports using RaveReports(Updated) I found out the the memo field does not display correctly or incorrect wrapping causing the text will spill-out of the area. and i notice if i change the zoom in/out, it also change the wrapping that sometimes display correct sometimes even worst.

i changed the ff properties but no effect.

Truncate, ContrainsRTF, anchor.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using the Delphi7 + Rave Reports 5.1.4. It is an old software. I have additional problems with RTF in DataMemo field. It can display Font in selected size but not the Italic or Bold. Everything is in the Font specified in the component and not from the content being displayed. Have you found any solution for the same our problem ?

Comment: No not yet. I am using Delphi 2009 but still the same.

Comment: I think there is some patch for Rave Reports 5.1.4.